# Python Flask authentication for google drive API on Heroku server

Tags: python, flask, heroku, google-drive-api

I am attempting to develop a web application in Python Flask that is able to traverse the google drive file system and deploy it on Heroku server. However I got stuck at the authentication step. When I start the application locally it works fine. After pressing the login button I am redirected to authentication window, I login to a google account and then files in my google drive's root are listed. However after I deployed my app to Heroku the homepage file shows up just fine but when I press login the app freezes and nothing happens for some time until I get client timeout error.
I checked the Heroku log and noticed that the authorization redirect link was printed in the log, so I tried to run the login again, copy the redirect link from the Heroku log and used it to access the authorization window. There I could choose an account to login with, but after confirming the login the authorization process froze, app never got the access and the whole process ended with the client timeout again. Here is what my python Flask file `app.py` looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

app = Flask(__name__)
service = None
creds = None
tree = None

def createServiceFromCreds():
    global service
    global creds
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

def checkForExistingCredentials():
    global creds
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

def validCredsExist():
    global creds
    checkForExistingCredentials()
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        return False
    return True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    loggedIn = validCredsExist()
    if loggedIn:
        createServiceFromCreds()
        page_token = None
        files = []
        while True:
            response = service.files().list(q="'root' in parents and trashed=false",
                                            spaces='drive',
                                            fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, webViewLink)',
                                            pageToken=page_token).execute()
            for file in response.get('files', []):
                files.append(file)
            page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
            if page_token is None:
                break
        return render_template("homepage.html", loggedIn=loggedIn, files=files)
    return render_template("homepage.html", loggedIn=loggedIn)

@app.route('/login')
def authorize():
    global creds
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        'credentials.json', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
    createServiceFromCreds()
    return redirect('/')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    global creds
    global service
    global tree
    creds = None
    service = None
    tree = None
    os.remove('token.pickle')
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is what my `Procfile` for Heroku looks like:

`web: gunicorn app:app`

And this is the `homepage.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
         {% if loggedIn %}
            <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
         {% else %}
            <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
         {% endif %}
    </ul>
    <h1>Welcome to homepage!</h1>
    {% if loggedIn %}
        {% for file in files %}
            {{ file }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

I am quite desperate by now. I am unable to find a way how to perform the google authentication on Heroku server so that I could access the google drive in there. I am new to all this so my understanding of web development or google authorization is quite limited. Would someone be able to help me with this or nudge me in the right direction to achieve what I am to?

Comment: What are your redirects set up in GCP? As a workaround could you authenticate locally and ssh over your token file?

Comment: If I authenticate locally and send my token to the server then the application works without any problems. That is, until I logout and then try to log back in, then it freezes again. As for the GCP I am not exactly sure. I followed the quickstart available on the google api page https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python and just modified it a bit to work in my flask app. However this is what I found in my credentials.json file I generated there:
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",

Comment: Make sure you have set up your project correctly, including the location the oauth screen should be redirected after authorisation. Check out [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret) for a guide

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. With its help I've managed to pull it off and the google authorization now works on the Heroku server.